# What is the reduce() function doing, in Swift

Tags: swift

I am referring [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) Apple documentation page.

I got the following code snippet from an article about `reduce` which gives a unique value set from an array :

```swift
func countUniques<T: Comparable>(_ array: Array<T>) -> Int {
    let sorted = array.sorted()
    let initial: (T?,Int) = (.none, 0)
        
    let reduced = sorted.reduce(initial) {
        return ($1, $0.0 == $1 ? $0.1 : $0.1 + 1) // Doubt here
    }
    return reduced.1
}

print(countUniques([1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4])) // prints 4
```

From what I know, `reduce` is generally used to sum up elements but here it's a little tricky and I am not able to understand what `return ($1, $0.0 == $1 ? $0.1 : $0.1 + 1)` is actually doing.

Comment: Explicit the ternary if, add intermdiaries values, don't anonymize parameters $0 & $1, print all values... That should be a good start for debugging, and understanding what's happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that `reduce` works by repeated applying a function (that is the closure you pass in) to an accumulator (that is the `initial`), for each element of the sequence:

```
var acc = initial
for element in array {
    acc = f(acc, element) // f is the closure
}
```

Now knowing that, this reduction will make a lot more sense if you give meaningful names to `$0.0`, `$0.1` and `$1`. Here I have renamed `$0` to `(prev, total)`, and `$1` to `curr`.

```
func countUniques<T: Comparable>(_ array: Array<T>) -> Int {
    let sorted = array.sorted()
    let initial: (T?,Int) = (.none, 0)
    
    let (_, total) = sorted.reduce(initial) { acc, curr in
        let (prev, total) = acc
        return (curr, prev == curr ? total : total + 1)
    }
    return total
}
```

`prev` is used to keep track of the previous element that we have seen. Notice how we always return `curr` as the first element of the pair. This is to say that the current element that we are seeing, becomes the "previous element" in the next iteration. Also note that it starts off `.none` (`nil`), as we have not seen anything yet.

If `prev` is not `curr`, we add 1 to `total`, otherwise we use the same `total`. In this way, we can count how many times we see a different element from the one just saw.

For a sorted array, "how many times we see a different element from the one just saw" is the same number as the number of unique elements, because the duplicates will all be grouped next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

`initial` not having labels makes that code too impenetrable.

Fixing that and using the `into` overload should make things more clear. But with either overload, `$0` is the accumulating value, and `$1` is the current iteration of the sequence being reduced.

```swift
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
  var countOfUniques: Int {
    sorted()
      .reduce(into: (previous: Element?.none, count: 0)) {
        if $0.previous != $1 {
          $0.count += 1
        }
        $0.previous = $1
      }
      .count
  }
}
```

---

If you write this with a more reusable case of `reduce`, you can disregard `$1`, but only if you name `$0`.

```swift
import Algorithms

[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4].uniqued().count
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// - Complexity: O(n)
  var count: Int {
    reduce(0) { count, _ in count + 1 }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debugging is a useful skill. If you don't understand, you can add breakpoints and see the values, conditional breakpoints with prints, etc, or directly `print()`.

Since the `reduce()` is "complex", let's explicit it:

Let's name the variables. It's a `reduce(_:_)`, so we know what mean the first and second parameter. The first one is "initial" at start, and is modified during the course of the iteration, so let's call it `partialResult`, and it will be the `finalResult` on last iteration, giving its value to the return function, here `let reduced =`. The second one is the element of the iteration:

```
let reduced = sorted.reduce(initial) { partialResult, currentIterationItem in
    return (currentIterationItem, partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem ? partialResult.1 : partialResult.1 + 1)// Doubt here
}
```

Let's remove the ternary if now, with an explicit if/else:

```
let reduced = sorted.reduce(initial) { partialResult, currentIterationItem in
    if partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem {
        return (currentIterationItem, partialResult.1)
    } else {
        return (currentIterationItem, partialResult.1 + 1)
    }
}
```

Let's use a temp variable which will holds the value returned:

```
let reduced = sorted.reduce(initial) { partialResult, currentIterationItem in
    var returnValue: (T?,Int)
    if partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem {
        returnValue = (currentIterationItem, partialResult.1)
    } else {
        returnValue = (currentIterationItem, partialResult.1 + 1)
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

Now, let's add logs:

```
let reduced = sorted.reduce(initial) { partialResult, currentIterationItem in
    print("Current Item to analyze: \(currentIterationItem)")
    print("Partial Result: \(partialResult) before")
    var returnValue: (T?,Int)
    if partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem {
        print("partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem")
        returnValue = (currentIterationItem, partialResult.1)
    } else {
        print("partialResult.0 != currentIterationItem")
        returnValue = (currentIterationItem, partialResult.1 + 1)
    }
    print("Return value: \(returnValue) which is partialResult at next iteration")
    return returnValue
}
```

You can try it now, but your example is not the best one. Why? Because it's using an already sorted array, and "4" is also the value of the last item, it could bring confusion...
Instead, let's use an array of `String`, single letters for better understanding (1 -> A, 2 -> B, 3 -> C, 4 -> D):

```
print(countUniques5(["A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","D"]))// prints 4
```

Okay, now, what are the logs:

```
Current Item to analyze: A
Partial Result: (nil, 0) before
partialResult.0 != currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("A"), 1) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: A
Partial Result: (Optional("A"), 1) before
partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("A"), 1) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: A
Partial Result: (Optional("A"), 1) before
partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("A"), 1) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: A
Partial Result: (Optional("A"), 1) before
partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("A"), 1) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: A
Partial Result: (Optional("A"), 1) before
partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("A"), 1) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: A
Partial Result: (Optional("A"), 1) before
partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("A"), 1) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: B
Partial Result: (Optional("A"), 1) before
partialResult.0 != currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("B"), 2) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: B
Partial Result: (Optional("B"), 2) before
partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("B"), 2) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: B
Partial Result: (Optional("B"), 2) before
partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("B"), 2) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: B
Partial Result: (Optional("B"), 2) before
partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("B"), 2) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: C
Partial Result: (Optional("B"), 2) before
partialResult.0 != currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("C"), 3) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: C
Partial Result: (Optional("C"), 3) before
partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("C"), 3) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: C
Partial Result: (Optional("C"), 3) before
partialResult.0 == currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("C"), 3) which is partialResult at next iteration
Current Item to analyze: D
Partial Result: (Optional("C"), 3) before
partialResult.0 != currentIterationItem
Return value: (Optional("D"), 4) which is partialResult at next iteration
```

We know the goal of the method, and we know how `reduce(_:_:)` works.

So what's happening?
We have a start `(nil, 0)`. We then, test the current element against `nil`, it's different, we'll have now (A, 1). Then, since it's sorted, we do the same for the remaining "A", it's the same, the `partialResult` is still (A,1). When entering next letter "B", it goes into the else, so we keep the letter "B" into partialResult, and we increment the second tuple value. We know have (B, 2), etc.

So, the tuple meaning is: first value: Current item, second value: counter of different items seen.
It works, because array if sorted. If it wasn't, the output would be totally wrong.

In my opinion, it's not good (as they is no explanation) code. It's a little hard to read, understand what's happening. A `Set` if possible would have been better, but it needs to be `Hashable` compliant.

Usually, when you need to create a `var` before `reduce(_:_:)`, prefer `reduce(into:_:)`.

In a nutshell: See intermediary values & decomplex code by breaking into multiple small steps...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a multi-step process to reverse-engineer this code:

1. Let us replace the closure‘s “shorthand argument names” (the `$0` and the `$1`) with meaningful names as deduced from the `reduce` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce). The `reduce` function’s closure’s parameters are (a) the “result” from the previous iteration; and (b) the current element from the array for the current iteration of the `reduce` closure:

   ```swift
   func countUniques<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> Int {
       let sorted = array.sorted()
       let initial: (T?, Int) = (.none, 0)

       let reduced = sorted.reduce(initial) { previousResult, item in
           return (item, previousResult.0 == item ? previousResult.1 : previousResult.1 + 1) // Doubt here
       }
       return reduced.1
   }
   ```

   Already, it is starting to be a little more clear. But let us continue our analysis.
2. If the [ternary](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID71) syntax (the `a ? b : c`) makes the meaning opaque, it is often useful to break it down into an `if`-`else` statement:

   ```swift
   func countUniques2<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> Int {
       let sorted = array.sorted()
       let initial: (T?, Int) = (.none, 0)

       let reduced = sorted.reduce(initial) { previousResult, item in
           if previousResult.0 == item {
               return (item, previousResult.1)
           } else {
               return (item, previousResult.1 + 1)
           }
       }
       return reduced.1
   }
   ```
3. OK, so what is `(T?, Int)` and the subsequent `.0` and `.1` syntax? That is a [tuple](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID329). It is a pair of values which is being used in three places, namely:

   - the `initial` value;
   - the first parameter of the closure, `previousResult`; and
   - the return value of the closure.

   You are apparently familiar with `reduce` that is passing a single value from one iteration to another (e.g., a simple sum). But when you see a tuple in a `reduce` function closure, that simply means that `reduce` is passing two values from one iteration to the next. So what are these two tuple elements?

   In the code, we see `previousResult.0` (the first element of the tuple) and `previousResult.1` (the second element of the tuple). So, what does that first element of the tuple represent?

   By looking at what the closure returns, we can infer that `previousResult.0` is simply the previous value in the array (notice that the `return` returns the current item in the array as the first parameter).

   How about the second element of that tuple, the `previousResult.1`? Well, we can see if the previous value is the same and the current value in the array, it simply returns `previousResult.1`, but if the values are different, it returns `previousResult.1` plus `1`. Clearly this is just the count of unique values encountered thus far. I.e., if the current array item is different than the previous item in the array, it increments the count.

   ```swift
   func countUniques3<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> Int {
       let sorted = array.sorted()
       let initial: (T?, Int) = (.none, 0)                             // first element of tuple is previous value in sorted array; second element is count of unique values encountered thus far

       let reduced = sorted.reduce(initial) { previousResult, item in
           let (previousValue, previousUniquesCount) = previousResult  // decompose the tuple's two elements into meaningful names
           if previousValue == item {
               return (item, previousUniquesCount)
           } else {
               return (item, previousUniquesCount + 1)
           }
       }
       return reduced.1                                                // the final result is the second element of the tuple returned by `reduce`
   }
   ```
4. Now that we can start to see what the routine is doing, we could translate this into imperative routine, replacing the tuple with two separate variables to represent the tuple’s two elements:

   ```swift
   func countUniques4<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> Int {
       let sorted = array.sorted()

       var previousValue: T?
       var count = 0

       for item in sorted {
           if item != previousValue {
               count += 1
               previousValue = item
           }
       }

       return count
   }
   ```

   Or, even more concisely:

   ```swift
   func countUniques5<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> Int {
       let sorted = array.sorted()

       var previousValue: T?
       var count = 0

       for value in sorted where value != previousValue {
           count += 1
           previousValue = value
       }

       return count
   }
   ```
5. Now, one can debate the merits of `reduce` with a tuple. It is a clever technique, but arguably makes the code harder to understand at a glance. Admittedly, once you have done it a few times, it becomes easier to interpret. I guess we are lucky that the author did not elect to make it even more “concise”:

   ```swift
   func countUniques6<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> Int {
       array.sorted().reduce((T?.none, 0)) { ($1, $0.0 == $1 ? $0.1 : $0.1 + 1) }.1
   }
   ```

   or

   ```swift
   func countUniques7<T: Comparable>(_ array: [T]) -> Int {
       array.sorted().reduce(into: (T?.none, 0)) { if $0.0 != $1 { $0 = ($1, $0.1 + 1) } }.1
   }
   ```

   As you can see, you can write very compact expressions with functional code, shorthand argument names, tuples, etc. There can even be a perverse pleasure in doing so. But generally we strive for code that is easily understood and maintained (except for those rare cases where we have to sacrifice these features for the sake of performance, which is not the case here).

---

Speaking of performance, this whole routine is somewhat inefficient. Notably, the algorithm is predicated upon first sorting the array. That is slow. It is also an inefficient use of space.

For example, if the array element values were hashable, using a `Set` would be more efficient and avoids the complexity of the above:

```
func countUniques8<T: Hashable>(_ array: [T]) -> Int {
   return Set(array).count
}
```

There is no need to build a separate sorted array, sorting each and every element of the array, simply to determine how many unique values there are. You only need to know whether the value has been encountered before. A `Set` accomplishes this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the solution in much cleaner way -

You just need to check previous element is equal to current if yes add it in total. That's it :)

```
func countUniques(_ array: [Int]) -> Int {
    var total = 0
    let countUnique = array.sorted().reduce(total) { prev, curr in
        total = (prev == curr ? total : total + 1)
        return total
    }
    return countUnique
}
```